# Confused about terminology in the many flavors of security

Tags: reference-request, terminology

I am learning about cryptography from diverse sources, and I have found terminology a bit confusing.

In principle, I understand the difference between the *symbolic model* and the *computational model*. However, then I am confused when I see things like :

- *information-theoretic security*,
- *computational security*,
- *concrete security*,
- *asymptotic security*,
- *perfect security*.

What is the relation of all these with the symbolic and computational models? What are the relationships between them?

Is there a source where I can make sense of the terminology in a unified fashion?

Comment: Where did you encounter the terms symbolic and computational model?

Comment: In the setting of protocol verification, for instance the following [survey](https://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/publications/BlanchetETAPS12.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain, I'll exercise these models on an example, namely that of LoR-CPA-security.

The LoR-CPA game $\operatorname{Priv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n)$ for a cipher $\Pi=(\operatorname{Gen},\operatorname{Enc},\operatorname{Dec})$ and a security parameter $n$ against a probabilistic [Oracle-Turing-Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) adversary $\mathcal A$ goes as follows:

1. $k\gets \operatorname{Gen}(1^n)$
2. Uniformly at random generate a bit $b\stackrel\$\gets\{0,1\}$
3. Define $\mathcal E(m_0,m_1)=\operatorname{Enc}_k(m_b)$
4. Run the adversary with encryption oracle access to $\mathcal E$: $b'\gets \mathcal A^{\mathcal E(\cdot,\cdot)}(1^n)$
5. Output 1 if $b=b'$ and else output $b$

Then we define the advantage $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n,q,t,s)=2\cdot \Pr[\operatorname{Priv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n)]-1$ where $\mathcal A$ must run in $t$ steps, only use $s$ cells of space and make at most $q$ queries to its oracle.

---

Now for the definitions:

- *Symbolic model*: From what I gather from [the linked paper (PDF)](https://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/publications/BlanchetETAPS12.pdf) this would take the above definition and remove all occurences of the security parameter and runtime / space restrictions from all algorithms, which should be equivalent to the notion that the only thing you know / can learn is the correctness property.
- *Perfect Security* / *Information-theoretic security*: They are the same and ask for a scheme that for all $n$: $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n,\infty,\infty,\infty)=0$ holds. This is not always achievable.
- *Asymptotic Security*: This one asks that there exists a negligible function $\varepsilon$ such that $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n,\operatorname{poly}(n),\operatorname{poly}(n),\operatorname{poly}(n))\leq \varepsilon(n)$ for all $n$ larger than some $n_0$ and some polynomial $\operatorname{poly}$.
- *Concrete Security*: This one demands a concrete relation / statement for the security of the scheme, i.e. there must exist some function $f$ such that $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cpa}}_{\mathcal A,\Pi}(n,q,t,s)\leq f(n,q,t,s)$ and it is up to the user to judge whether $f$ is small enough for a given parameter set to be considered secure for their application. This is the preferred notion for non-complexity-theoretical results.

The *computational model* is then an umbrella term for the last three bullet points from above. 
*Computational security* is usually an umbrella term for the last two bullet points from above.
Even though I used CPA-security as the example, the above applies to all security notions that define an advantage, except for the algebraic inference in the symbolic model.